# javascript: multiple stop image toggle

Tags: javascript, toggle

I am trying to make an image button on my website toggle wallpaper change frequency options (off,5,10,15,30,30,90 minutes). I have created a custom image for each step (so the user can be aware of the current setting).  When implemented the user should be able to repeatedly hit the button to toggle through all 7 options, ultimately looping back to the beginning.

I have some code to swap between two images (below), and have used it for other options on the site (wallpaper on/off), but I just can't figure out a way to get the code to work for my new needs.

```
if (imageId == 'image1') {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        var img = document.getElementById(imageId);
        img.src = (img.src.indexOf("40_unlocked.jpg") != -1) ? "40_locked.jpg" : "40_unlocked.jpg";
    }
}
```

I expect I will need to determine the current image, then use a switch to advance to the next option, something like the below, but I don't know how to determine the current image - hoping someone can offer a suggestion - thanks in advance!

```
function changeIt(img) {
    var src;
    switch (img.id) {
        case "example":
            src = "n.gif";
            break;
        case "example2":
            src = "n2.gif";
            break;
        case "example3":
            src = "n3.gif";
            break;
    }
    img.src = (img.src.indexOf("jj.gif") < 0 ? "jj.gif" : src);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to toggle image change frequencies using javascript. You should totally drop that and use jQuery.

Comment: @Domecraft - I have not needed to venture into JQuery yet, would this allow me to keep everything client-side?

Comment: Yes. jQuery makes your life so much easier when animating in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started
Name your images n0.gif through n6.gif.

```
toggle.onclick=function(){
  //isolate the number of the current image
  var num=this.src.split('.gif')[0].split('n')[1]-0;
  //add 1 and take mod 7 to loop it back to 0 if it needed
  num=++num%7;
  //set the src to the new image
  this.src='n'+num+'.gif';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an array of all of the src urls & then toggle it like this.

```
function changeIt(img)
{
    var src=img.src;
    images=['src1','src2','src3','src4','src5','src6','src7'];
    index=images.indexOf(a);
    if (index+1>6)
    {
        index=0;
    }

    else
    {
        index+=1;
    }
    img.setAttribute('src',images[index]);
}
```